# Why and who has established that $1\, cal \equiv4.186\, J$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, experimental-physics, si-units, metrology

At one time, it was mistakenly believed that an object contained a certain amount of '*heat fluid*' that could flow from one body to another.
of '*caloric fluid*' that could flow from one body to another.

Just as a curiosity: it is known that in **Joule's experiment** there is a correlation between gravitational potential energy $2mgh$, heat $Q$ and temperature change $\Delta T$.

[image]

Before Joule's work, heat was measured with a unit called a calorie (cal).
In particular, a kilocalorie (kcal) was defined as the amount of heat required to raise the temperature of a kilogram of water from $14.5 °C$ to $15.5 °C$.

> Why and who has established that $1\, cal =4.186\, J$?

Comment: I'm not clear about what the question is here. The conversion from one calorie is a definition, and as you say yourself how much one calorie is has a historical origin. What is the question exactly?

Comment: @Steeven Why does it have to be 1 cal = 4.186 J and not e.g. 1 cal = 3.456 J (for example)?

Comment: As @Steeven indicated and the question describes, it didn't have to be that way.  Definitions where made for each and the conversion factor those definitions follows from them.  Why is the conversion from F to C what it is?  Same reason.  From feet to yards to meters to centimeters?  Same reason.  Not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was Joule's [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Prescott_Joule#The_mechanical_equivalent_of_heat) itself that established the equivalency of ~770 foot-pounds of mechanical work to 1 btu of heat energy.

The unit *joule* was [introduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule#History) only ~50 years later in 1889.

In comments you asked,

> why 1 cal it is equivalent to a precise value 4.186 J and not another value?

because the amount of energy needed to raise 1 g of water by 1 C is the same as is delivered by a force that can accelerate 4.186 kg by 1 $m/s^2$ acting over 1 m of distance.

(Actually if you read the Wiki article on the [calorie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie) you'll see that the energy needed to heat water by 1 C depends slightly on the starting temperature and pressure of the water)

> what is the privimive equivalence or calculus steps to obtain 4.186 J?

It's an empirically measured relationship, as described in the linked article. Joule took a source of known mechanical work and used it to heat a known mass of water, then measured how much the water heated up.

Comment: Thank you very much. Hence what is the privimive equivalence or calculus steps to obtain 4.186 J?

Answer (score 2):

Joule's experiment showed that 1 Joule of work is necessary to cause the internal energy of 1 gm of water to rise, such that its temperature rises 1 degree C.  This is equivalent to what 1 calorie of heat does.  So he demonstrated this equivalence between heat and work.

Joule divided by the amount of work  in Joules he did in his experiment by the amount of water in gm and the temperature rise in C, and it came out to 4186 J/gm-C.  And it takes 1 cal of heat to raise the temperature of 1 gm of water by 1 C, so, what would you conclude?

Comment: Yes, I have understood this...but why 1 cal it is equivalent to a precise value 4.186 J and not another value?

Comment: @Sebastiano, because the amount of energy needed to raise 1 g of water by 1 C is the same as needed to accelerate 4.186 kg by 1 m/s^2 with a force acting over 1 m of distance.

Comment: @ChetMiller, is the proper value 4186 J/kg-C (you claimed 4186 J/g-C)?

Comment: I hope not.  If you feel that way, you should flag the moderators and have them investigate that.  I once had to do it.

Comment: @David White. I'm not sure.  Come to think of it, if I remember correctly, it is 4.184.  I always have to look  that up.

Answer (score 2):

The specific heat capacity of water has been measured to be $$c_{H_2O}=4.186\frac{J}{g K}$$

So if you take $m=1g$ of water and want to increase its temperature by $\Delta T=1K$, you will need an energy of

$$\Delta E=cm\Delta T = 4.186\frac{J}{g K}\cdot1g\cdot1K=4.186J$$